# How can I map a folder over the network?

Tags: ubuntu

On windows file explorer, I can see a folder on another machine by typing `\\10.12.23.34\aDirecctory` (that is a Ubuntu machine).

How can I do that on ubuntu machine? I try putting `\\10.12.23.34\aDirecctory`, it said `Could not find "/home/mysuer/\\10.12.23.34\aDirecctory`

Thank you.

Comment: Here's a link to a similar question on askUbuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/119668/share-ext4-partition-over-network/119684#119684

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how the folder is shared. I am assuming (since you said it works for windows) that Ubuntu is exporting using samba. I am also assuming that you are using nautilus or whatever they call the file manager on unity. So, if these assumptions are correct, using this address in the file manager should work:

```
smb://10.12.23.34/aDirectory
```

If you edit your question to be more specific, I will update my answer.